# Orientability of $\gamma^n\oplus \gamma^n$ WITHOUT characteristic classes

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, orientation

I was curious to find an argument to show orientability of the $2n$-bundle $$\gamma^n\oplus \gamma^n$$ where $\gamma^n$ is the canonical $n$-bundle over the infinite grassmannians $Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$. I now that using the first Stiefel-Whitney class would be easy, but I don't want to use such machinery (I'd have to introduce too many things in my work -obstruction theory I think-)

I'd prefer some precise hint rather than complete solutions, because I wanna work out details on myself, and more importantly get used to such reasonings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ real matrix and $A \oplus A$ denotes the $(2n) \times (2n)$ block matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & A \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $\det(A \oplus A) > 0$.

Comment: Clear. I though about this "easy" fact during an exam where I was asked to prove orientability of a direct sum of bundles, and I think I wrote this thing, but then I was uncertain about the fact that I can choose the trivialisation map on the cartesian product (I see the whitney sum as the pullback via the diagonal of the cartesian product $\xi \times \xi$) to be the ones induced by the trivialisation maps $h\times h$ and not (for example) $h \times h'$. But now I realise that all I need to do is to exhibit an orientable atlas, and not showing that ANY atlas is orientable (which is false :P)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the hint!